# How can I change color of items on Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-color

I have a Toolbar, I want to change background to Black but by default items color is black and I want to change their color to gray, how can I do that ? Thanks you so much:
[My Image about Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TTk3.jpg)

And this is my toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#2196F3"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

My styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of icons?

Comment: yes, change to gray

Comment: Did you create those icons or imported them?

Comment: `<item
        android:id="@+id/slash_toolbar"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_voice"
        app:showAsAction="always" />` this is how i create it

Comment: Ok, while creating icons you can choose the color. I'll show you how

Comment: so can't do it by code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change icon colors in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142062/how-to-change-icon-colors-in-android-studio)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953503/how-to-set-icon-color-of-menuitem

Comment: @JasonMomoa Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating an icon or vector asset, you can select the color

[image]

Click on the color selector.

If you want to change color in code then add `app:iconTint="@color/yourcolor"` in your MenuItem for change the Icon color.

```
<item
android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
android:id="@+id/action_share"
android:title="@string/action_share"
android:orderInCategory="200"
app:iconTint="@color/yourcolor"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

For changing the 3 dots icon color, try adding this in styles.xml

```
<style name="YourCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is this what you've been looking for?

Comment: yeah, this also is a way, so i want to know that can do it by custom a  theme  in styles.xml

Comment: If your main theme is light and your ActionBar is dark, your ActionBar/Toolbar must use the theme `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`

Comment: three vertical dots, how can i change it's color ? @Dev Sharma

Comment: no, your solution just work with icons which is added by me, but "three vertical dots" of menu is not worked

Comment: Updated. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Change the tint attribute of the icon.

Via xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/slash_toolbar" 
android:title="" 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_voice" 
app:showAsAction="always" 
android:tint="@android:color/white"/>
```

Via [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953613/5791681):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        Drawable drawable = menu.getItem(i).getIcon();
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

To change the three dots color [put it in your style.xml in AppTheme:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35454669/5791681)

```
<!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: where I can put `android:tint="@android:color/white"` ?

Comment: yeah: the below code is worked, but with the icon "3dots" is not worked

Comment: I've update the answer to show how to change the "three dots" color